# Double countdown using recursion function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursion using JavaScript, without using global variables but i am not sure that the program can be possible like desire output.

Question is "Given a non-negative integer n, create a double countdown-pattern in the output."
Example:
If you ran doubleCountdown(5) you would also get the following output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
4
3
2
1
0
```

I have tried following ways:
In this way getting down to up output but not exact output:

```js
double_countdown(5);
function double_countdown(n){
    if(n == 0){
        console.log(n);
        return
    }
    console.log(n);
    double_countdown(n-1);
    console.log(n);
}
```

In this ways, i have used global for desired output but not standard way.

```js
let second_n = 0;
let double_count =0;
double_countdown(5);
function double_countdown(n){
    if(n == 0 && double_count == 0){
        double_count = 1;
        double_countdown(second_n-1);
        console.log(n);
    }
    if(n == 0){
        return
    }else{
        second_n +=1;
    }
    console.log(n);
    double_countdown(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the single countdown as a recursive function and have a double countdown function simply call it twice.  This keeps all the parts simple.

```js
const countdown = (s, e = 0) => 
  s < e ? [] : [s, ...countdown (s -1, e)]

const doubleCountdown = (n) => 
  [...countdown (n, 1), ...countdown (n - 1, 0)]

console .log (doubleCountdown (5))
```

You can then log the answer however you want for your homework.  Perhaps something like `for (let n of doubleCountdown (5)) {console .log (n)}`

Comment: perfect, of cause ... just combine the most simple/straightforward countdown implementation twice (each with different initial values)

Comment: Yes, simple enough.  More interesting would be if we were asked to get something like `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,   4, 3, 2, 1, 0,   3, 2, 1, 0,   2, 1, 0,   1, 0,   0]`.  Then the obvious answer would be doubly recursive.

Comment: No, Function should not be called twice. Output should come by single calling as I did. What about my answer? I have called the double_countdown only once.

Comment: We only call `doubleCountdown` once.  That this calls another function twice should not be a big deal, unless your instructor is trying to make your homework as difficult as possible.  But you can certainly do this using optional defaulted parameters to keep track of the initial value and whether you're on the first or second loop.  That just seems silly, though.

Comment: For instance, this would do it, but it seems stupidly complex compared to the above:  `const doubleCountdown = (n, i = n, firstPass = true) => firstPass && i < 2 ? [i, ... doubleCountdown (n - 1, n - 1, false)] : firstPass ? [i, ...doubleCountdown (n, i - 1, true)] : i < 1 ? [0] : [i, ...doubleCountdown (n, i - 1, false)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the recursive function in a way that it keeps track of its recursion state by providing and working with more parameters than just the required first parameter (which is the current count down value).

Thus one would implement e.g. a function which is capable of running the count down cycle `N` times. And a `double_countdown` respectively `countDownTwice` function could be derived from such a generic implementation.

```js
function countDownNTimes(value = 0, times = 1, initialValue) {
  // initially invoked with an `undefined` value for `initialValue`.
  initialValue ??= value;

  console.log(value);

  if (times >= 2) {
    if (value <= 1) {

      // does trigger a new recursion cycle with minimized boundaries.
      countDownNTimes(initialValue - 1, --times, initialValue);
    } else {

      // stays within the current recursion of minimized boundaries.
      countDownNTimes(--value, times, initialValue);
    }
  } else if ((times >= 1) && (value >= 1))  {

    // stays within the current, final recursion of reastablished boundaries.
    countDownNTimes(--value, times, initialValue);
  }
}
const countDownTwice = value => countDownNTimes(value, 2);

console.log('... countDownTwice(5) ...');
countDownTwice(5);

console.log('... countDownNTimes(3, 3) ...');
countDownNTimes(3, 3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: No @Peter your answer not as required. Thank you for trying..

Comment: @DevD ... ok, I see, but it's pretty easy to adapt it according to the boundary requirements. The approach itself does not change. Give me some minutes.

Comment: @DevD ... the solution was updated according to the OP's requirements of changing count down boundaries within the recursion cycles.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, after trying many times, I got the answer:

```js
double_countdown(5);
function double_countdown(n,sc=0){
    if(sc == 0) sc = n;
    if(n == 0 ) return ;
    console.log(n);
    double_countdown(n-1,sc);
    console.log(sc-n);
}
```

Comment: _"... If anything wrong then please help for more improve."_ ... if one focuses on recursion from a functional point of view, there should be actually exactly a single state change (here the logging of `n` and `sc-n`) for the count down value with each recursion. Then a guard for `(n == 0)` which does return before logging was not needed as well.

Comment: Okay Then would you please send it as correct as you said.